# Fixing a 0xc0000225 error in VMware Fusion

Tags: windows, virtualization, vmware

A few days ago I had to force shut down my iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2012) running 10.11.6 because it wouldn't wake up. VMware Fusion 6.0.6 was running.

Now when I start VMware Fusion I get in this endless loop of error messages:

[image]

I tried to look for solutions online but they were all for actual installs of Windows, not installs through a virtual machine.

How can this be fixed (ideally, without losing any informations on the Windows system?)

Comment: Aside for the fact that VMware Fusion 6.0.6 [is not supported under OS X 10.11](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2088571), VMware has its own Support Site and Discussions Community which may be a better place then here, since the issue is so specific to Windows and VMware Fusion.

Comment: True. I am currently looking for the customer number to log on their site and ask them... might take a while. It's not officially supported under 10.11 but ran quite well until last week ;)

Comment: Please post the content of the vmx file to pastebin, github or a file hoster

Comment: @klanomathcould you tell me how to do it?